# Angular7 custom pipe: I got a problem with country Name and country Code when display to table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
country code: "ab", "aa", "fr", ...
```

I would like a custom pipe that transform a countryCode to a countryName like: `"ab" → "Abkhazian"`, `"ch" → "Chinese"`, `"fr" → "France"` (etc) when displayed in my table.
The data in request body still needs to be a countryCode in order to send it to `restfulApi.Can`.
Would someone be able to help me?
Thanks !
*(I am using angular 7)*
*Note: When displayed in my table, it shows the country code because I sent the country code to the POST method API.
So doing a GET request to display it will show the country code.

Comment: please post the code you tried

Answer (score 1):

**country-pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'countryTransform'
})
export class CountryTransformPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(countryCode: string, args?: any): String | undefined {

    //Some service should hold the information in a map where key = country code and 
    //value = country description
    const countryCodeMap: Map<string,string> = 'load this map from a service' 
    return countryCodeMap.get(countryCode);
  }

}
```

Then in your html where you want to transform the country code in country description you do something like this

```
<tr> {{ countryCode | countryTransform }} </tr>
```